# How do I fix error in Tensorflow Neural Network Regression

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, non-linear-regression

I don't understand why my code wouldn't run. I started with the TensorFlow tutorial to classify the images in the mnist data set using a single layer feedforward neural net. Then modified the code to create a multilayer perceptron that maps out 37 inputs to 1 output. The input and output training data are being loaded from Matlab data file (.mat)

Here is my code..

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from scipy.io import loadmat
%matplotlib inline
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import learn

import sklearn
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from warnings import filterwarnings
filterwarnings('ignore')
sns.set_style('white')
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons

X = np.array(loadmat("Data/DataIn.mat")['TrainingDataIn'])
Y = np.array(loadmat("Data/DataOut.mat")['TrainingDataOut'])

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=.5)
total_len = X_train.shape[0]

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 500
batch_size = 10
display_step = 1
dropout_rate = 0.9
# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 19 # 1st layer number of features
n_hidden_2 = 26 # 2nd layer number of features
n_input = X_train.shape[1]
n_classes = 1

# tf Graph input
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 37])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None])

def multilayer_perceptron(X, weights, biases):
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)

    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)

    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer


# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes], 0, 0.1))
}

biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes], 0, 0.1))
}

# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(X, weights, biases)
tf.shape(pred)
tf.shape(Y)
print("Prediction matrix:", pred)
print("Output matrix:", Y)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred-Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(total_len/batch_size)
        print(total_batch)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch-1):
            batch_x = X_train[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
            batch_y = Y_train[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c, p = sess.run([optimizer, cost, pred], feed_dict={X: batch_x,
                                                          Y: batch_y})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch

        # sample prediction
        label_value = batch_y
        estimate = p
        err = label_value-estimate
        print ("num batch:", total_batch)

        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print ("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", \
                "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
            print ("[*]----------------------------")
            for i in xrange(5):
                print ("label value:", label_value[i], \
                    "estimated value:", estimate[i])
            print ("[*]============================")

    print ("Optimization Finished!")

    # Test model
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred), tf.argmax(Y))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    print ("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: X_test, Y: Y_test}))
```

when I run the code I get error messages that has to do with dimensional issues. I have just modified tutorial codes that I saw online to fit my problem. Why would my code run. I am new to python. Please help.

Here are the error messages:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\ann\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed, input_tensors_as_shapes_needed, debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
    670           graph_def_version, node_def_str, input_shapes, input_tensors,
--> 671           input_tensors_as_shapes, status)
    672   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as err:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\ann\lib\contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     65             try:
---> 66                 next(self.gen)
     67             except StopIteration:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\ann\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    467   finally:

InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 19 and 37 for 'MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,19], [37,19].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-751c8673d311> in <module>()
     68 
     69 # Construct model
---> 70 pred = multilayer_perceptron(X, weights, biases)
     71 tf.shape(pred)
     72 tf.shape(Y)

<ipython-input-1-751c8673d311> in multilayer_perceptron(X, weights, biases)
     46     layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
     47 
---> 48     layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
     49     layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
     50 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\ann\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py in matmul(a, b, transpose_a, transpose_b, adjoint_a, adjoint_b, a_is_sparse, b_is_sparse, name)
   1814     else:
   1815       return gen_math_ops._mat_mul(
-> 1816           a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
   1817 
   1818 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\ann\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py in _mat_mul(a, b, transpose_a, transpose_b, name)
   1215   """
   1216   result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("MatMul", a=a, b=b, transpose_a=transpose_a,
-> 1217                                 transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
   1218   return result
   1219 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\ann\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    765         op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, output_types, name=scope,
    766                          input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
--> 767                          op_def=op_def)
    768         if output_structure:
    769           outputs = op.outputs

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\ann\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in create_op(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_shapes, compute_device)
   2506                     original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
   2507     if compute_shapes:
-> 2508       set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
   2509     self._add_op(ret)
   2510     self._record_op_seen_by_control_dependencies(ret)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\ann\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in set_shapes_for_outputs(op)
   1871       shape_func = _call_cpp_shape_fn_and_require_op
   1872 
-> 1873   shapes = shape_func(op)
   1874   if shapes is None:
   1875     raise RuntimeError(

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\ann\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in call_with_requiring(op)
   1821 
   1822   def call_with_requiring(op):
-> 1823     return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
   1824 
   1825   _call_cpp_shape_fn_and_require_op = call_with_requiring

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\ann\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py in call_cpp_shape_fn(op, input_tensors_needed, input_tensors_as_shapes_needed, debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
    608     res = _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed,
    609                                   input_tensors_as_shapes_needed,
--> 610                                   debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
    611     if not isinstance(res, dict):
    612       # Handles the case where _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl calls unknown_shape(op).

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\ann\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed, input_tensors_as_shapes_needed, debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
    674       missing_shape_fn = True
    675     else:
--> 676       raise ValueError(err.message)
    677 
    678   if missing_shape_fn:

ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 19 and 37 for 'MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,19], [37,19].
```

I have corrected the typo error I made. I now get this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-946a0b048e42> in <module>()
     93             # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
     94             _, c, p = sess.run([optimizer, cost, pred], feed_dict={X: batch_x,
---> 95                                                           Y: batch_y})
     96             # Compute average loss
     97             avg_cost += c / total_batch

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\ann\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    787     try:
    788       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 789                          run_metadata_ptr)
    790       if run_metadata:
    791         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\ann\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    973                 'Cannot feed value of shape %r for Tensor %r, '
    974                 'which has shape %r'
--> 975                 % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
    976           if not self.graph.is_feedable(subfeed_t):
    977             raise ValueError('Tensor %s may not be fed.' % subfeed_t)

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (10, 1) for Tensor 'Placeholder_3:0', which has shape '(?,)'
```

Comment: The first line of error I get is: InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 19 and 37 for 'MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,19], [37,19].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define your `layer2` you are using the wrong weights an biases, it should be `'h2'` and `'b2'` instead of `'h1'` and `'b1'`:

```
layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
```

Comment: and @ James thanks for your comments. I have updated the code and have fewer errors.

Answer (score 1):

A valid matrix multiplication requires the width of the first matrix to match the height of the second matrix.

The error is saying, for your hidden_layer_2 matmul, the first input has shape batch_size x 19, the second input has shape 37 x 19. Their dimension doesn't match.

You probably meant "h2" for layer_2, but you have a typo "h1" there.